# Computed field default based on other field

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-9

```
preload = fields.Boolean(related='project_id.preload', string='Preload Templates')

part_template_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'project.part.template', string='Part Templates', required=True,
default='_default_part_template_ids')

  def _default_part_template_ids(self):
        domain = [('case_default', '=', True)]
        return self.env['project.part.template'].search(domain)
```

my goal is to change part_template_ids default based on preload field. If preload is True then part_template_ids default='_default_part_template_ids' if preload is false then default for part_template_ids is false too. how can i do this?

Comment: If you check `self` inside the default methods you've made, you'll see that it's empty (as the record hasn't been created yet), so you can't make a default value depend on another value through that way. I'd use `onchange` method, each time `project_id` (or `preload`) changes, fill in `part_template_ids` with the data you want.

Comment: @forvas setting a default on `preload` and writing an onchange method depending on it (with Chaban33 logic) should be enough. That worked very well in older Odoo versions, but i don't know if the new API is working as well.

Comment: @CZoellner I think what you wrote works now too, it would be the best solution as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to add a default value to `preload`

```py
preload = fields.Boolean(
    related='project_id.preload', string='Preload Templates',
    default=False)
```

That will trigger onchange events, even on initial creation. You can use that to fill default values for other fields.

```py
@api.onchange('preload')
@api.multi
def onchange_preload(self):
    """ Preloads part templates if set to true"""
    if self.preload:
        domain = [('case_default', '=', True)]
        self.part_template_ids = self.env['project.part.template'].search(domain)
    else:
        self.part_template_ids = self.env['project.part.template']
```